# Create Log System

Tags: logging

Using spring, I want to develop a system which can log custom api request and response details.

Lets say I have two api:

1. create user: this will create a users and information I want to store in log will be in below format 
   a. name - xyz
   b. age - 25
   c. api name - /createuser
2. modify user : will change the status of user and information I want to store in log will be in below format  : 
   1.status - inactive
   2.name - xyz
   3.api name - /modifyuser

since two api have different format of data so how can I build this in generic way so that if I have third api and I can accommodate it easily.
Note: this should be asynchronous and dont want to set the values in impl class.

Answer (score 0):

we can use Template Design Pattern here.